# Removing or protecting from leaf and flower stains

Tags: hard-landscape, pavers

I have a patio with some pavers and a walkway with some blue stones. between myself and my neighbor, we do have a lot of leaf and flower droppings. These droppings do cause a lot of stains.

I tried to remove the stains with vinegar, bleach and detergent mix and also tried a stain remover from amazon. Nothing seems to help. I have following questions:

- Is there anything else that I can try as a stain remover?
- Can I put something like a sealer for the stones and pavers to not have the stains?

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: what kind of stone is a blue stone?  Slate? Granite? Limestone?

Comment: It’s a blue stone

Comment: Basalt probably